# Speed up/slow down TilEm on Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8.1, performance, speed, emulator

I have a program named TilEm, which is an emulator for Ti-84 graphing calculators and the like. The main issue that I am having is that there are only two speeds for the emulator: a regular graphing calculator speed, and the fastest system speed possible.

The problem with the former is that it's much too slow: I have to press each button twice for the result to register. The problem with the latter is that it's too fast: because it speeds the graphing calculator application up to one hundred times its regular speed, the calculator turns off every few seconds.

So, I'm like Goldilocks, and I want to control the speed of the application itself, since there are no settings in the calculator itself to extend the time before it sleeps, and I have no patience to go through the code for the application. Any ideas as to how to control an app's running speed on Windows 8?